# mysqli fetch_assoc with conditional statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display multiple parts of a query on my page using fetch_assoc and some conditional statements. My first while loop is displaying the correct information, but loops 2 and 3 are not displaying any information. What would be the correct way to filter my results?

```
require_once('inc/connection.inc.php');

//create database connection
$conn = dbConnect();

//create SQL
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM menu';

$result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());
```

> ```
> while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
>
> if($row['category'] == 'appetizers'){ 
>     echo $row['title']; 
>     echo $row['price'];
> }
> ```
>
> }
>
> ```
> while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
>
> if($row['category'] == 'salads'){ 
>     echo $row['title']; 
>     echo $row['price'];
> }
> ```
>
> }
>
> ```
> while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
>
> if($row['category'] == 'desserts'){ 
>     echo $row['title']; 
>     echo $row['price'];
> }
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not do it like this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

   if($row['category'] == 'appetizers'){ 
     echo '<h1>Appetizers</h1>';
     echo $row['title']; 
     echo $row['price'];
   }  

   if($row['category'] == 'salads'){ 
     echo '<h1>Salads</h1>';
     echo $row['title']; 
     echo $row['price'];
   }  

   if($row['category'] == 'desserts'){ 
     echo '<h1>Desserts</h1>';
     echo $row['title']; 
     echo $row['price'];
   } 

}
```

i.e., use the conditions in a single `while` loop.

OR

You can use [mysqli_data_seek](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php) to reset the pointer to the first record and re-use the same resource multiple times

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

   if($row['category'] == 'appetizers'){ 
     echo $row['title']; 
     echo $row['price'];
   }  
}

mysqli_data_seek($result,0);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

   if($row['category'] == 'salads'){ 
     echo $row['title']; 
     echo $row['price'];
   }
}

mysqli_data_seek($result,0);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

   if($row['category'] == 'desserts'){ 
     echo $row['title']; 
     echo $row['price'];
   }
}
```

Comment: This works if all the results were listed together, but in this case they will be listed separately.

Comment: Using this, you would get a heading for each loop iteration. I think OP wants to group them. I'd just run three separate queries with `WHERE category = 'appetizers'`, `WHERE category = 'salads'`, etc

Comment: *data seek* is pretty snazzy :)

Comment: Well, I had to come up with something attractive xD

Comment: Very nice. Works great!

Comment: Cool! So I'm guessing you're using the data seek approach, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{

  if($row['category'] == 'appetizers'){ 
    echo $row['title']; 
    echo $row['price'];
  }  

  if($row['category'] == 'salads'){ 
    echo $row['title']; 
    echo $row['price'];
  }  
  if($row['category'] == 'desserts'){ 
    echo $row['title']; 
    echo $row['price'];
  }  
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, I don't think this would work. Doesn't the pointer need to be set back to the first record each time?

Comment: don't think $row affect any output?

Answer (score 0):

you are running query result one time and fetching it three time so need to query result three time

```
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());
$result1 = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());
$result2 = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());
```

then loop

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()){
while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()){
```

Also you can use mutiple if() in loop like:-

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
if($row['category'] == 'appetizers'){ 
    echo $row['title']; 
    echo $row['price'];
}
if($row['category'] == 'salads'){ 
    echo $row['title']; 
    echo $row['price'];
}
if($row['category'] == 'desserts'){ 
    echo $row['title']; 
    echo $row['price'];
}
}
```

Comment: Adding the multiple query results is working. Would you consider it 'best practice' to do it this way?

Comment: Why run the same query multiple times?

Comment: @Phil you can try OP's question for output?

Comment: What I meant is that you might as well run it once and collect all the rows in an array, then loop per category. Saves multiple, redundant trips to the DB

Comment: @Phil there is more way to do that but according me it's simplest and also found helpful for OP. thanks for suggestion you can edit answer if you have any other suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is something like this...

```
$categories = ['appetizers', 'salads', 'desserts'];

if (!$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT title, price FROM menu WHERE category = ?')) {
    throw new Exception($con->error, $con->errno);
}

$stmt->bind_param('s', $category);

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        throw new Exception($stmt->error, $stmt->errno);
    }
    $stmt->bind_result($title, $price);

    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo $title, $price;
    }
}
```

What I've done is execute a prepared statement for each category in the `$categories` array. This will group your `menu` rows together under each category in the order you want.

Comment: Awww Phil, you always overshadow me with better answers :p